# Get Data from JSON file into jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I've tried to load data from a JSON file into jQuery.But nothing happened.Is there anything wrong with my JSON file define or the misuse of jQuery function?
Here is my json file.

```
{ 
"jQueryquiz" :
 [
    {
        "title":"A",
        "answer":"asd"
        },
    {
        "title":"B",
        "answer":"qwe"
        },
    {
        "title":"C",
        "answer":"zxc"
    }
]   }
```

Here is my hmtl file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').click(function(){
                $.getJSON('quiz.json',function(data){

                    var html="";
                    html+=data.jQueryQuiz[0].title;
                    $('#results').html(html);
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <input type="button" class="button" value="Start!"/>

        <div id="results">

        </div>



</body>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Where's the quiz.json file located? You cannot just read files from your OS - they need to be served.

Comment: No error..Just nothing happened.The json file and the html file are in the same folder...

Comment: Open the console in developer tools - the fact nothing is shown on the page, does not meen there's no error :)

Comment: I'm sorry..%>_<%.. it says"XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: Yup. See my comment above - you need to serve the file, or its contents, from somewhere (server, static address etc.) - you can't read local files using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my problem is to host the json file in some place like "myjson". The reason is just as Traveling Tech Guy said,"you can't read local files using AJAX".

Answer (score 0):

The $.getJSON() function returns a jqXHR object which must resolve before you can access you data.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('quiz.json').done(function(data){
    var html="";
    html+=data.jQueryQuiz[0].title;
    $('#results').html(html);
});
```

The jQuery docs for getJSON() go into more detail about this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/